# What is the difference between SRS and Requirement Analysis?

Tags: requirements, srs

My understanding of Requirement Analysis is that it is a process and the document created during this process is SRS (Software Requirement  Specification).

Comment: You're right, what's the question?

Comment: Does Stackoverflow allow these kinds of questions? It isn't a technical question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @CharlesB said: You're right.
Although of course, there are many different terms in the industry for the specification which is the "output" of the process. The SRS is specified by [IEEE](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/search/searchresult.jsp?queryText=software%20requirements%20specification&refinements=4294965216&pageNumber=1&resultAction=REFINE). Especially in the US, SRS is the most common term for the artifact.

Answer (score 0):

requirements are what your program should do,they shouldn't specify the how, but the what

specifications are how you plan to do it and how to achieve the requirements